# About for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and was confronted with a basic question about for loop:

```
var vacationSpots = ["Tokyo", "London", "New York"];

for (var i = vacationSpots.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log("I would like to visit " + vacationSpots[i]);
}
```

I wonder why for the stop condition we need `i >= 0` rather than `i = 0`. I tried `i = 0` but nothing but an error showed. Could you tell me the difference between `i >=0` and `i = 0`? I thought through `i = 0`, the code will stop at Tokyo which is in position 0 in the array.

Comment: `i = 0` is *assignment*, not equality comparison.

Comment: [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](//stackoverflow.com/q/22873)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder why for the stop condition we need `i >= 0` rather than `i = 0`

Because it's not a "stop condition". It's a "continuation condition". Loop runs while it is true.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement

> The condition expression is evaluated. If the value of condition is true, the loop statements execute. If the value of condition is false, the for loop terminates. If the condition expression is omitted entirely, the condition is assumed to be true.

(and yeah, don't confuse `i = 0` and `i == 0`).

Answer (score 0):

> why `i >= 0` rather than `i = 0`

This is because `i = 0` means that you want to assign `0` into `i` variable. However `loop` needs a `true` condition to keep working that is why a conditional statement is required. So by passing `i >= 0`, you are saying to loop that keep working **while** `i` is greater than `0`.

To experiment what you can try is `i == 0` instead of `i = 0` but then the loop will only work when `i` is equal to `0`

Comment: "keep working until i is greater than 0" - nope. It's __while__, not until.

Answer (score 0):

1.First look at your array which has more then one properties: "Tokyo", "London", "New York"

2.Then in order to go through those properties, you need to go through those index ( which means array location, like tokyo in index=0, in first place, london in index=1, second place and New york in index=2, third place)

3.so look here: var i = vacationSpots.length; i >= 0; i--

i = 3, because there has 3 properties

and you need to count those propertie from first place to final place: i >= 0

then count to decrease with --

hope this could help